# Rally "Building Your First App" app does not run

Tags: javascript, rally

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/guide/first_app) and am having problems.

First of all, Rally have disabled JSONP by default and warn against turning it back on. Without it you cannot run a developing app locally. So that's a giant PITA. We soldier on. I am running it by creating a custom HTML app in the rallydev.com environment, each time I change the code, and viewing it that way.

I have only gotten to the "Add a CardBoard to the app" section and am already having JS errors. From the developer console:

```
sdk.js:formatted:69475 Error: success callback for Deferred transformed result of Deferred transformed result of Deferred threw: TypeError: Cannot read property 'project' of undefined
    at Ext.define.getFullyQualifiedName (sdk.js:formatted:78147)
    at Ext.define.build (sdk.js:formatted:78170)
    at Ext.define.buildCompositeArtifact (sdk.js:formatted:78209)
    at Ext.define.getModel (sdk.js:formatted:96694)
    at Ext.define._buildColumnsFromModel (sdk.js:formatted:96901)
    at Ext.define._parseColumns (sdk.js:formatted:96898)
    at sdk.js:formatted:67474
    at Ext.define.notify (sdk.js:formatted:67523)
    at Ext.define.register (sdk.js:formatted:67509)
    at Ext.define.then (sdk.js:formatted:67408)Ext.override.log @ sdk.js:formatted:69475Ext.define.error @ sdk.js:formatted:66221(anonymous function) @ sdk.js:formatted:67479Ext.define.notify @ sdk.js:formatted:67523Ext.define.register @ sdk.js:formatted:67509Ext.define.then @ sdk.js:formatted:67408Ext.define.then @ sdk.js:formatted:67347Ext.define._parseColumnsAndRows @ sdk.js:formatted:96825Ext.define.onModelsRetrieved @ sdk.js:formatted:96728Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModels.success @ sdk.js:formatted:96736(anonymous function) @ sdk.js:formatted:1108
```

From sdk.js:formatted in the console, this code is where it's happening, lines 78145 thru 78149. `context` is undefined:

```
    getFullyQualifiedName: function() {
        var context = this.getContext();
        return context.project ? oidStr = "project." + Rally.util.Ref.getOidFromRef(context.project) : oidStr = "workspace." + Rally.util.Ref.getOidFromRef(context.workspace),
        "Rally.domain." + this.getWsapiVersion() + "." + oidStr + "." + this.getTypePath().replace(/\//g, "")
    },
```

ETA: I tried copying the complete code from the tutorial and it also fails (same error). So if anybody from Rally sees this, this is broken. A workaround for the JSONP kerfuffle would be fantastic as well.

ETA: I followed @KyleMorse 's suggestion and went to the 2.1 instructions. I copied the final code from that into my App.js. I can now run locally, but with JS error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Project/54629369420?fetch=O…rationEstimateUnitName%2CReleaseEstimateUnitName%2CTaskUnitName%2CChildren. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:1337' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I added a new app with this into Rally. It loads, but the columns don't display and I see JS error:

```
sdk.js:65 Error: success callback for Deferred transformed result of Deferred transformed result of Deferred threw: TypeError: Cannot read property 'project' of undefined
    at Ext.define.getFullyQualifiedName (sdk.js:72)
    at Ext.define.build (sdk.js:72)
    at Ext.define.buildCompositeArtifact (sdk.js:72)
    at Ext.define.getModel (sdk.js:89)
    at Ext.define._buildColumnsFromModel (sdk.js:89)
    at Ext.define._parseColumns (sdk.js:89)
    at sdk.js:62
    at Ext.define.notify (sdk.js:63)
    at Ext.define.register (sdk.js:62)
    at Ext.define.then (sdk.js:62)Ext.override.log @ sdk.js:65Ext.define.error @ sdk.js:61(anonymous function) @ sdk.js:62Ext.define.notify @ sdk.js:63Ext.define.register @ sdk.js:62Ext.define.then @ sdk.js:62Ext.define.then @ sdk.js:62Ext.define._parseColumnsAndRows @ sdk.js:89Ext.define.onModelsRetrieved @ sdk.js:89Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModels.success @ sdk.js:89(anonymous function) @ sdk.js:1
```

Comment: The `XMLHTTPRequest` JS error is a CORS / HTTP Access Control issue because I am trying to access across domains (localhost to rally1.rallydev.com, i think). I don't get how anybody gets this code to run locally.

Comment: what browser are you using?  is it possible some settings in your browser have disabled cors?  or are you behind a proxy that is stripping the cors headers?  sdk 2 and rally1 fully support cors, so this shouldn't be a problem...

Comment: I'm using Chrome, and I added a CORS Chrome Extension "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *" as well. Without that extension, I get an error complaining, "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:1337' is therefore not allowed access." I don't think I have any settings disabling CORS, and I am not behind a proxy.

Comment: In Safari, where I have no CORS extension, I don't get the header error as in my previous comment; but I do get 401 errors trying to load User, Subscription, and "all" to the page.

Comment: hmm...  the 401s are unauthenticated errors.  i don't think we've seen the cors issue you're experiencing before though.  chrome periodically has issues with caching cors preflights for too long, but usually clearing cache/cookies resolves that issue.

Comment: what version of chrome are you using?  in safari did you have an active CAAC session in that browser?  have you tried firefox?  i'd love to get to the bottom of this...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113657/discussion-between-kewpiedoll99-and-kyle-morse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're just getting started, may I suggest using the most recent version of the SDK and its corresponding guide: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/first_app

The JSONP issue you are referencing is new since the 2.0 docs were published.  The 2.1 docs mention this limitation.  You will definitely want to use Rally App Builder to run your app to get around this issue.

You definitely should not need to constantly copy/paste the app into a Custom HTML panel to test it- that's super painful and was one of the main reasons we created Rally App Builder in the first place.

I wasn't able to reproduce the other issue you are having.  Can you try again using the new guide and report back if you're still having issues?

Comment: Will do - thank you. I was hoping you would see this question!

Comment: See above edits; I am now following the 2.1 guide and using 2.1 SDK. I found the workaround to the JSONP issue and can load locally, but still get errors instead of successful run. Thanks.

Comment: Check out this very related answer as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37581282/agile-central-example-app-failing/37581565#37581565