# Agile Central example app failing

Tags: rally, agile

After following the directions listed [here](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/first_app) , I received the following error in Google Chrome's Developer Tools:

```
sdk-debug.js:147611 Error: success callback for Deferred transformed result of Deferred transformed result of Deferred threw: TypeError: Cannot read property 'project' of undefined
at Ext.define.getFullyQualifiedName (sdk-debug.js:163998)
at Ext.define.build (sdk-debug.js:164052)
at Ext.define.buildCompositeArtifact (sdk-debug.js:164152)
at Ext.define.getModel (sdk-debug.js:196664)
at Ext.define._buildColumnsFromModel (sdk-debug.js:196985)
at Ext.define._parseColumns (sdk-debug.js:196977)
at sdk-debug.js:146417
at Ext.define.notify (sdk-debug.js:146514)
at Ext.define.register (sdk-debug.js:146481)
at Ext.define.then (sdk-debug.js:146299)
```

JSONP is enabled on my subscription, and I have gotten messages to read out onto my console. Also, I have gotten web-services to successfully respond to requests.  This one here is new to me. This "should" work, but it doesn't. Is this a bug with the example itself?

The full source-code of the example as I've implemented it is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8vrHv4tZecPNHBKc3k4TEhLclk/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, how embarrassing.  This is definitely a bug with the Rally.ui.cardboard.CardBoard component.  On the plus side, you can work around it by simply including the current context in your example code.

```
var cardBoardConfig = {
    xtype: 'rallycardboard',
    types: ['Defect', 'User Story'],
    attribute: 'ScheduleState',

    context: this.getContext(), //<-- NEW CODE HERE

    storeConfig: {
        filters: [this.iterationCombobox.getQueryFromSelected()]
    }
};
```

It is generally good practice to provide the current context to all components anyway, but all components should also be smart enough to just use the default if it is not specified.

I will file a defect to fix the card board component to use the default context correctly and to also fix the example to explicitly pass the context as well.  Thanks for reporting this issue and sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Adding the context attribute fixed the issue. I'd appreciate this change being in your documentation sooner rather than later.  Additionally, please note, your examples require that JSONP be enabled. This is not also not noted in the examples documentation.

Comment: The docs will be updated with the context shortly.  Also, you only need JSONP enabled if you're launching the app directly from the file system.  The preferred method now is to use Rally App Builder, which is discussed in detail in the Getting Started section...

Comment: Kyle, at the risk of sounding argumentative, the method discussed for launching apps is to view the App-debug.html page and refreshing. While there may be a subtle footnote in the docs somewhere that says what you're saying, you need to be explicit.  Subtle is too cute by half.

Comment: Thanks for the honest feedback.  Sometimes it's hard to get that first-timer perspective when writing the docs since we do this all the time.  Also the first version of that guide predated the JSONP security issues and the advent of Rally App Builder and it seems we could have done a better job integrating it into that guide in the meantime.  Apologies for your wasted time.  Glad you're up and running though!  I'm going to revisit that guide and try to make it clearer that RAB is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks Kyle.  please note, I wrote that note before my first coffee this am.  You may want to review the how-to-build-an-app videos 1-8 as well, if refreshing App-debug.html is no longer the best-practice. Those are the best instructional materials I've seen for making apps, and makes a clear point of using App-debug.html for quick develop-test cycles.

Comment: Ah, great.  Happy you found those. I think those videos may pre-date Rally App Builder as well.  I agree, they are awesome.  It would be great to update them to reference Rally App Builder...

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a problem with how rallycardboard's configuration handles entries in the "types:" attribute. If you have either 'User Story', or 'Defect' it will work. However, if you have both, it will not.

This works:

```
var cardBoardConfig = {
        xtype: 'rallycardboard',
        types: ['Defect'],
        attribute: 'ScheduleState',
        storeConfig: {
            filters: [this.iterationCombobox.getQueryFromSelected()]
        }
    };
    this.cardBoard = this.add(cardBoardConfig);
```

This works:

```
var cardBoardConfig = {
        xtype: 'rallycardboard',
        types: ['User Story'],
        attribute: 'ScheduleState',
        storeConfig: {
            filters: [this.iterationCombobox.getQueryFromSelected()]
        }
    };
    this.cardBoard = this.add(cardBoardConfig);
```

This (copied directly from the cited example) does not work:

```
var cardBoardConfig = {
        xtype: 'rallycardboard',
        types: ['User Story', 'Defect'],
        attribute: 'ScheduleState',
        storeConfig: {
            filters: [this.iterationCombobox.getQueryFromSelected()]
        }
    };
    this.cardBoard = this.add(cardBoardConfig);
```